# AWS Systems Manager (SSM) fails to UpdateInstanceInformation on SageMaker instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I often get Cloudwatch Authorization alerts because the role attached to my SageMaker instance doesn't seem to have enough SSM (Systems Manager) permissions to **UpdateInstanceInformation**. My understanding is that the agent **amazon-ssm-agent** wants to hit an AWS API but fails to do so.

My Role has full SSM permissions:

```
{
        "Action": [
            "ssm:*",
            "ssmmessages:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

but the error persists:

```
 {
   "eventVersion": "1.05",
   "userIdentity": {
      "type": "AssumedRole",
      "principalId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX:SageMaker",
      "arn": "arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/sagemaker_prod_Notebook_Instance_Role/SageMaker",
      "sessionContext": {
          "sessionIssuer": {
              "type": "Role",
              "principalId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/sagemaker_prod_Notebook_Instance_Role",
              "accountId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "userName": "sagemaker_prod_Notebook_Instance_Role"
          }
      },
      "invokedBy": "im.amazonaws.com"
   },
   "eventSource": "ssm.amazonaws.com",
   "eventName": "UpdateInstanceInformation",
   "sourceIPAddress": "im.amazonaws.com",
   "userAgent": "im.amazonaws.com",
   "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
   "errorMessage": "An unknown error occurred",
   "requestParameters": {
       "instanceId": "i-045f627a2d2e469b1",
       "agentVersion": "2.3.714.0",
       "platformType": "Linux",
       "agentName": "amazon-ssm-agent"
   },
   "eventType": "AwsApiCall"
}
```

Has anyone seen this before ?

Comment: AWS provides manages policies for ssm, such as `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore`? Have you tried with those?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late but I had a similar issue so I reached out to AWS Support and it seems to be a somewhat of a bug.

I was told that the AWS Sagemaker team has ssm installed by default. The Sagemaker notebook runs in an aws service account, although when a customer assigns Sagemaker a role in their own account the role cannot perform UpdateInstance information via the customer assigned role.

Support suggested I create a lifecycle config and leverage the following code sample to fix it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/disable-uninstall-ssm-agent/on-start.sh